# Perform eigendecomposition on Gram matrix without calculating it.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have the matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times K},N>> K$. $N$ is very large (let us say 600K). I want to calculate the K smallest eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the Gram matrix $XX^T$, however, fitting such a matrix in memory is impossible. I remember that there was a trick to calculate it by iteratively evaluating $X(X^Ty)$, where $y$ is a vector. This way we never calculate $XX^T$ and we are able to obtain the eigenvectors. Any lead on this?

Answer (score 1):

Since $N≫K$, the matrix $X$ is at most rank $K$, and so is $XX^⊤$. Hence, $XX^⊤$ must have at least $N-K$ many zero eigenvalues. Zero-Eigenvalues are the smallest eigenvalues of $XX^⊤$, since it is a symmetric positive-definite matrix. To find associated eigenvectors, simply solve $X^⊤ v = 0$.